# jQuery show() hide() on mouse over image

Tags: jquery

i have some problems with a bit of javascript. i want to display a div when hovering an image:

```
        <div class="slideshow">
            <img src="img/picture1.jpg" id="picture1" />
            <img src="img/picture2.jpg" id="picture2" />
        </div>

        <div class="pic1desc">
                <h3>Headline</h3><br />
                Text
        </div>

        <div class="pic2desc">
                <h3>Headline</h3><br />
                Text
        </div>
```

Here is my javascript-snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pic1desc').hide();
$('.pic2desc').hide();

//When the Image is hovered upon, show the hidden div using Mouseover
$('#picture1').mouseover(function() {
$('.pic1desc').show();
});

//When the Image is hovered away from, hide the div using Mouseout
$('#picture1').mouseout(function() {
$('.pic1desc').hide();
});


});
```

This isn't working at all. Anybody got an idea for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: that is working fine see for console errors, if this is not working , there might be other errors

Comment: may be you forgot to include the jquery script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/sVZgp/) is working check this out :

*However you can reduce your code to*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.pic1desc','.pic2desc').hide();


//When the Image is hovered upon, show the hidden div using Mouseover
 $('#picture1').hover(function() {
   $('.pic1desc').show();
},function() {
  $('.pic1desc').hide();
});

//same for `#picture2`
```

**OR**

*name your div class, as  image class*

```
<div class="picture1">
            <h3>Headline</h3><br />
            Text
    </div>

    <div class="picture2">
            <h3>Headline</h3><br />
            Text
    </div>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.picture1','.picture2').hide();


//When the Image is hovered upon, show the hidden div using Mouseover
 $('img[id^="picture"]').hover(function() {
   $('.'+ $(this).prop('class')).show();
},function() {
  $('.'+ $(this).prop('class')).hide();
});
```

This is dynamic and works for any number of elements.

> And yes make sure you are loading (including) **jQuery.js**. That might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks - i've loaded a depricated jquery version :/ I think I need more coffee!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like thise:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '#picture1', function(){
    // By giving this function two triggers, the same action is performed for each trigger
    $('.pic1desc').toggle();
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#picture1', function(){
    // By giving this function two triggers, the same action is performed for each trigger
    $('.pic1desc').toggle();
});
```

another solution might be this (if you want advanced actions to happen):

```
$('#picture1').on('mouseover', function(){
    // something on mouseover
    // this way you get more space for larger/more special actions
)}.bind('mouseout',  function(){
    // something on mouseout
    // Same space for mouseout
});
```

Comment: `live()` is depricated in since 1.8 in jQuery

Comment: Thanks, fixed it :) Still getting used to on(), been using live() for a while

Answer (score 0):

Do like this: use `mouseenter()` it's having a `callback` method eg. `mouseleave()`

```
$('#picture1').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.pic1desc').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.pic1desc').hide();    
});


$('#picture2').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.pic2desc').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.pic2desc').hide();    
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jEJL/)